# DataCorrupted: could not read block in file

Tags: python, postgresql, odoo-10

I have a database that was corrupted for some reason. I keep getting this error whenever I try to edit the record :

```
        pg_dump: Error message from server : Error: could not read block 62826 in file "base/64121/111107": read only 0 of 8192 bytes
```

When i try to get databae backup this error occur:

DataCorrupted: could not read block 3 in file "base/64121/66381" : read only 0 of 8192 bytes

Comment: You have suffered a crash or something else that has caused disk corruption. The most practical next step is to restore from a recent backup onto a different machine while you investigate the machine that had problems and figure out why.

Comment: I am using postgresql and suddenly my postgres updated 9 to 13 version. May i know the data corruption is occur because of updated postgres? @RichardHuxton

Comment: postgres doesn't update itself, it is something you have setup on your computer. But yes version 13 of PostgreSQL will see a version 9 data file as being corrupted in various ways.

Comment: I have a backup but that backup took a month ago. I don't have a recent database backup to restore the data so how to retrieve my database without any data loss. Please give a solution to solve this issue.. Thanks for advance @RichardHuxton

Comment: You should 1) take an immediate backup of all the postgresql directories and 2) remove v13 and reinstall the exact version of postgresql you had before and 3) join the official mailing lists for more detailed help. However, you should be prepared to use that backup

Comment: Kindly provide the contact details for further process @RichardHuxton

Comment: Go to the postgresql.org website for details on how to subscribe to the mailing lists